# Simple string reverse program in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings

I want to learn how to write *good* code. Starting off with simple programs for now. So any suggestions regarding style, readability or more efficient ways of implementation, etc. would really be appreciated!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  bool running = true;

  while(running == true)
  {
    string input;
    cout << "[Enter 'exit' to exit the program]\n";
    cout << "Enter the text you want to reverse: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    if (input.compare("exit") == 0)
    {
      running = false;
      break;
    }

    reverse(input.begin(), input.end());
    cout << "The reversed version of your text is: " << input << endl << endl;
  }      
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost never compare with booleans `while (running)` or `while (!found)`.

Comment: It doesn't handle unicode (or any multi-byte encoding)

Comment: @JoopEggen why not? I hope you didn't mean to say *never compare two booleans against each other*

Comment: @Celeritas comparing booleans always is a rare enjoyment, usable for equivalence and more. Therefore that "almost." But in case of `(running == false) == false` one can someone hear thinking.

Comment: The for loop should also be `if (!getline(cin, input) || input == "exit")`.

Answer (score 27):

### Don't `using namespace std;`

It is considered bad practice because of possible name collisions, ... Although nobody will hurt you, as this is such a small program :)

### Don't compare booleans to booleans

Things like `running == true` are completely unnecessary, as `running` is already a condition in itself. Just use `running`.

### You don't need `running`

The variable `running` is unnecessary. You need one for nested loops (breaking out of both), but for single loops, a single `break` and an infinite loop is preferred.

### Why are you using `compare`?

Seeing `input.compare("exit") == 0` would send me right to the docs, as I don't know what the return value of `compare` is.

```
if (input == "exit");
```

is more clear.

### Don't flush 2 times in a row (or at all)

`std::endl` prints a new line, and then flushes `stdout`. This results in a performance hit, so it is better to output an actual newline. In your case:

```
std::cout << something << "\n\n";
```

Note that on some platforms (or if you need to), you have to flush the steam to see the output. In this case it is better to be explicit and use `std::flush`.

### You're not using the command line parameters

So why name them? You can just omit the names, or define a `main` which takes no parameters:

```
int main(int, char**) {} //1)
int main() {} //2)
```

I prefer option 2.

### Your code uses implementation specific behavior

`std::string` is defined in the `string` header. Not every compiler includes `string` with `iostream` or `algorithm` (VS doesn't), so you have to include it explicitly. Don't rely on automatic includes.

### Technically, you don't need `return 0;`

Only for `main`, if you omit `return 0;`, the compiler will add it for you, so technically, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: A minor point: the behavior is implementation specific, not "implementation defined"; the latter is a term of art in the standard, and requires a compiler to document its behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @PeteBecker, could you please expand on the difference between the two of them?

Comment: @Olzhas How can you say that something is implementation defined? Well, you have to try. Compile the code, and see. That's probably clear. But implementation specific is when you don't actually *need* a compiler. You can just open the files and see which file is included in which. That's how I understand it, I hope I not wrong :)

Comment: @Rakete1111, or you can just search in the C++ standard. I'm not sure about the difference, but I have another idea. I'll wait for Pete.

Comment: @Olzhas Search in the standard for what? Both are dependent on the implementation.

Comment: @Rakete1111, I mean you don't need to compile anything to know if the behavior is implementation defined, you just need a fresh copy of the working C++ standard draft.

Comment: @Olzhas Fair enough, I'll wait as well :)

Comment: When the C++ standard says that something is "Implementation defined" it means that a conforming implementation must **document** what it does. In the case of header files, C++ implementations are allowed to put other `#include` directives inside headers (which is different from C). So when you `#include <iostream>` you **might** get all the stuff from `<string>` as well. That's implementation-specific (or whatever other term you like). It's not implementation-defined, because the C++ standard does not require implementations to document their `#include` structure.

Comment: "*Don't using namespace std;*" Why not? This advice is only valid for header files (or the files that are meant to be included). "*Don't compare booleans to booleans*" what do you want them to be compared to then? Perhaps you mean *constants* like `true`/`false`.

Comment: @luk32 Not really. Possible name collisions can still happen in the source file. It also includes a lot of common names, `string`, `list`, `vector`, `for_each`, ... which are thus not available. Yes I meant that.

Comment: @Rakete1111 But they are containted to the source file. Personally I don't use `using namespace`, although here it's used as it's meant to be - Importing the namespace. Your argument is kind of hypothetical and goes against readability which is a fact. If the program was a a little bit more complex you'd need 10 `using std::XX;` statements or prepending everything with `std::` I am not sure if that is a better option. It might be debatable, but I don't think it should be shrugged off as a bad habit, again unless it's a header file, when you could provoke clashes and make the include unusable.

Comment: @luk32 I don't see how prefixing everything with `std::` harms readability. If the a class defines for example a `reverse` function, and there is `using namespace std;` at the top of the source file, you'll get ambiguous functions. But yes, sometimes it is not necessary due to the coding style (e.g. every function starts with an upper case).

Comment: "Seeing input.compare("exit") == 0 would send me right to the docs"... seeing "str == "literal"" sends me straight to the docs. I'd wager it's much more likely a programmer understands that a `compare` function returns 0 for equal than that they will know a string literal is not treated as a pointer in an `==` statement in c++. Leave it to operator overloading to make things confusing.

Comment: @Millie That was just a funny way of saying it. I don't think `compare` should be used that way. It returns the exact position of a difference in the strings. String literals *are* treated like arrays (and decay into pointers) in *every* statement. And yes, I believe a programmer should know that by heart, it is not that hard.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using `compare` that way... it serves its purpose. And I don't see anything in the docs stating the return value has to be the exact position of a difference in the strings (not that I agree this matters); can you point me to a reference? And since string literals decay into pointers, one would expect it to act like a pointer in an `==` statement (i.e. be compared as an address, not as the memory it points to).

Comment: @MillieSmith [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)  Not really, not in in modern C++ at least. There I would expect every string to be `std::string`, and not `const char*`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 in a perfect world :/. Teams are often slow to adopt new programming technology, and I work at a place that has mostly char buffers as opposed to std::string. I only see "negative value", "zero", and "positive value" in that link. I don't see a reference to the exact position of the string. The "possible implementation" they provide actually returns -1 and 1 when one string is the start of the other string and their lengths are different.

Comment: @MillieSmith Oh wow, I always thought that it returned the exact position :/ Sorry. Well yes, but we have to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 10):

In addition to previous answers:

1. You should check stream state after input (for example user can hit Ctrl+Z and enter or you can reach end of input file).
2. `return 0;` is not necessary in the `main` function.
3. Also you can move this code to the function and then replace `break;` with `return;`

My version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        std::string input;
        cout << "[Enter 'exit' to exit the program]\n";
        cout << "Enter the text you want to reverse: ";

        if (!getline(std::cin, input) || input.compare("exit") == 0)
            break;

        std::reverse(input.begin(), input.end());
        cout << "The reversed version of your text is: " << input << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A small nitpick, in the code below:

```
string input;
cout << "[Enter 'exit' to exit the program]\n";
cout << "Enter the text you want to reverse: ";
getline(cin, input);
```

I would move string input down next to where it is used in getline(...):

```
cout << "[Enter 'exit' to exit the program]\n";
cout << "Enter the text you want to reverse: ";
string input;
getline(cin, input);
```

Just helps to keep common code together. In a small example like this it is easy to excuse, but say there were 20 or more statements in between string input and getline. A reader would have to remember that input was defined while reading the other, unrelated, statements.

Small, but something to keep in the back of your mind.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the "type exit to exit" thing. What if someone wants to reverse "exit" → "tixe"? Simply use the standard for ending programs, ^C (Control-C). You don't even need to implement anything. If someone wants to exit they simply Control-C.

Final:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

  while(true)
  {
    string input;
    cout << "Enter the text you want to reverse: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    reverse(input.begin(), input.end());
    cout << "The reversed version of your text is: " << input << endl << endl;
  }      
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using SIGINT may be the standard for ending programs (although I've never seen it named so), but in general you'll have then to handle this signal, otherwise you'll quit without any cleanup. Also, it's implementation-specific, namely to POSIX. Not sure how an app on Windows can handle Control-C. Would be better to just say like "Enter the text <...> or press Enter to exit".

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, you can post it as another answer.

Answer (score 4):

While you are starting you should eliminate as much bad practice as possible.

1. Do not use `namespace std`; This is bad practice and will hurt you later on. So as soon as possible remove it and start adding `std::` whenever needed.
2. `std::reverse` is a general purpose routine, so I would suggest that you explore different ways to reach that goal.

   ```
   for (auto it = input.rbegin(); it != input.rend(); ++it) {
       std::cout << *it++;
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
   ```

   Note that this piece of code will leave your string unaffected, whereas you current code actually inverts the string and then prints that out.

Comment: (My favourite compromise is the likes of `using std::cout;`.)

Comment: I would not be surprised if **`cout`** ing the entire string once would be more efficient than **`cout`** ing the same string one character at a time.

Comment: @coderodde That might be true, but the main reason to do it this way is that the data remains unchanged

Comment: I downvoted because you're using auto& it. You're lucky that any temporary can be converted to const ref, which is why referred to object is alive. Anyway, it should be auto it

Comment: @Olzhas True, normally i only use auto with range based loops. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: @Olzhas This actually won't even compile.

Comment: @misco Why not edit the answer to fix the code?

Comment: @Ruslan, are you sure of it? I'm kinda bad in type deduction rules of auto and decltype. Let me check in Scott Meyer's EMC++ book. It's going to take quite long time

Comment: @Olzhas well, at least I've checked this with g++ 5.2 and clang++ 3.7, they say `non-const lvalue reference to type 'reverse_iterator<[...]>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'reverse_iterator<[...]>'` (clang output; gcc's is similar).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what others said, your program is running now because `iostream` happens to have an `#include <string>` in it but this is not required. It's good practice to include what you're using so you know the program will work in any case, in addition to your 2 includes you should add

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 3):

The only tip I can give in a so short program is that you can eliminate the **`running`** boolean variable:

```
while(true)
{
    string input;
    cout << "[Enter 'exit' to exit the program]\n";
    cout << "Enter the text you want to reverse: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    if (input.compare("exit") == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    reverse(input.begin(), input.end());
    cout << "The reversed version of your text is: " << input << endl << endl;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually want user input to break out of your program rather than using Ctrl-C, you could do something like this:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    while (true) {
             cout << "Enter the text you want to reverse: ";

             std::string in, answer;

             getline(cin, in);
             std::reverse(in.begin(), in.end());

             cout << "The reversed version of your text is: " << in << endl << endl;
             cout << "Would you like to reverse another string (y/n)? ";

             getline(cin, answer);

             if (answer.compare("n") == 0) {
                break;
             }
    }
}
```

I won't repeat what's been said about your basics, but rather have implemented them in this example.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really necessary in this case, but if you're writing the reverse of a large string, then you shouldn't reverse it in place and then print. Rather print it directly:

```
std::copy(in.rbegin(), in.rend(),
   std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

Using [`std::ostreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator) is to be preferred over using [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) in a loop because the later suffers overhead from constructing [a sentry object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry) for each single character, whereas the former only needs a single sentry.

Comment: Have a look at [miscco's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142211/93149).

Comment: @greybeard I didn't saw that before, thanks for pointing it out. Still I think my answer is justified: it shows the only (?) way to do what's probably the simplest here: reverse printing of a string (in a single output operation) See my edit.